# how to write SQL Query for 3 column values in one field?

Tags: php

I Want answer like yuvi yuvi@gmail.com 9874563214, if user search name email mobile means my ans come like this.

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT name,email_id,mobile_number FROM user_information WHERE (name LIKE '".$user_search."%'OR email_id LIKE '".$user_search."%' OR mobile_number LIKE '".$user_search."%') AND (status='Active')");
$res=mysql_num_rows($sql);
```

Comment: Read/implement http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Comment: Can we have some close votes here? Looks like the OP has been deleted anyway.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this below code

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', name,email_id,mobile_number) as details FROM user_information WHERE (name LIKE '".$user_search."%'OR email_id LIKE '".$user_search."%' OR mobile_number LIKE '".$user_search."%') AND (status='Active')");
```